# How to get a Path variable that implements P: AsRef<Path> + ToString interface in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to use some function provided by a someone on github:
https://docs.rs/escposify/latest/escposify/device/struct.File.html#method.from_path
But as I read the API documentation, I came accross a problem with this function. It states that it takes something that implements `AsRef <Path>` and also `ToString`.

```
pub fn from_path<P: AsRef<Path> + ToString>(path: P) -> File<File>
```

Here's my code:

```
let path = Path::new("//192.168.100.8/Receipt Printer").to_string_lossy();
let file = File::from_path(path);
let mut printer = Printer::new(file, None, None);
```

it throws an error:

```text
error: the trait bound `Cow<'_, str>: AsRef<Path>` is not satisfied
label: required by a bound introduced by this call

note: required by a bound in `escposify::device::File::<W>::from_path`
label: required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Here's the implementation from [the source code](https://docs.rs/escposify/latest/src/escposify/device.rs.html#43-50) that I could get:

```
pub fn from_path<P: AsRef<path::Path> + ToString>(path: P) -> File<fs::File> {
    let fobj = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .open(&path)
        .unwrap();
    File { fobj }
}
```

How should I put my filepath (`"//192.168.100.8/Receipt Printer"`) in this case ?

Comment: Why do you use `to_string_lossy`?

Comment: It throws error: `Path` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
label: `Path` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; call `.display()` when I use just `Path::new()`

Comment: Use `to_string_lossy` at the site where you need `Display` then. Definitely do not use the result of `to_string_lossy` for actually interacting with the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have simply used `Path` directly, without `to_string_lossy()`… at least if it weren’t for the fact that the library’s trait bounds are wrong.

```
pub fn from_path<P: AsRef<path::Path> + ToString>(path: P) -> File<fs::File> {
    let fobj = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .open(&path)
        .unwrap();
    File { fobj }
}
```

The only line above that happens to be using `path` is the `.open` line, invoking [`OpenOptions::open`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.open), which only requires `AsRef<Path>`.  The `ToString` trait is not used anywhere in that method, but the fact that it appears in the generic bound precludes passing an actual `Path` to `from_path`, since `Path` does not implement `ToString`, as it cannot be always losslessly converted to UTF-8.

[`Path::to_string_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.to_string_lossy) should not be used other than to label files in user interfaces for informational purposes.  It should never be used for paths which you may actually need to access later.

Fortunately, escposify also offers a more generic [`File::from`](https://docs.rs/escposify/0.4.1/escposify/device/struct.File.html#method.from) trait method, which allows you to open a file yourself and pass it to the library:

```
let path = Path::new("//192.168.100.8/Receipt Printer");
let fobj = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
    .write(true)
    .create(true)
    .open(&path)?;
let file = File::from(fobj);
let mut printer = Printer::new(file, None, None);
```

You can also use the string literal directly, i.e. pass `&str` like [@piojo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72066210/3840170) suggests; for toy programs that are fine using a hardcoded path, this should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

`&str` implements both `AsRef<Path>` and `ToString`, so you should be able to `let path = "//192.168.100.8/Receipt Printer";` and use that directly.

Comment: it turns out, you're right. I need to modify my code into: `let file = File::<fs::File>::from_path(path);`. The `path` variable is regular `&str` type